# A sequence where $d(x_{n}, x_{n+1})\leq\frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n\geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Suppose I've got a sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with the property that $d(x_{n}, x_{n+1})\leq\frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

I'm trying to prove that $d(x_{m},x_{n}) \leq \frac{1}{m-1}$ for all $2 \leq m \leq n$.

MY ATTEMPT:

Fix $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2 \leq m \leq n$. Define the integer $k=n-m$. Since $m\leq n$ we are guaranteed that $k \geq 0$. Then write:

$d(x_{m},x_{n}) = d(x_{m},x_{m+k}) \leq d(x_{m},x_{m+1})+d(x_{m+1},x_{m+2})+\dots + d(x_{m+k-1},x_{m+k})$

$=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}d(x_{m+j},x_{m+j+1})$
$\leq \sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{(m+j)^2}$

So it would seem that I need to show that $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{(m+j)^2} \leq \frac{1}{m-1}$. I have no clue how to do this. I am unable to add up this summation. Am I even attempting this in the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or more simple
$$
\frac1{k^2}<\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k
$$
and then apply telescoping sums.

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you. I have managed to use this to show that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(m+j)^{2}} < \frac{1}{m-1}$. I know this is a bit of a stupid question, but does this then mean that I can write $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(m+j)^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{m-1}$? I feel like I'm cheating a bit when I say that.

Comment: If you start with $j=1$, then the bound is $\frac1m$. For me the form $$\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\frac1{k^2}\le\frac1{m-1}-\frac1{n-1}\le\frac1{m-1} $$ looks easier to understand.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, so what I have got is exactly what you have above except rather than with "$\leq$", I have instead "$<$". Is that being a bit too meticulous? I guess its true that $a<b$ implies $a\leq b$.

Answer (score 5):

By drawing the graph of $y=\frac1{x^2}$ you can see that
$$\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\frac1{k^2}<\int_{m-1}^{n-1} \frac{dx}{x^2}<\int_{m-1}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac1{m-1}\ .$$